# Can EF6 generate my model objects from a ref cursor returned by an oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Can EF6 generate my model objects from a ref cursor returned by an oracle stored procedure??

So my current workplace is in the middle of a switch from using webforms to MVC5.

We would like to use EF6 and Oracle stored procedures. A lot of the models that we want to implement will be selecting data from multiple tables(our database is massive). We already have some stored procedures already as well.

I either need to be able to tell EF6 to map my models to the results of a stored procedure or explicitly tell EF6 which table each of my models attributes is coming from.

The other option would be to create oracle views for each model.

I've been googling around for a while and I'm having a hard time finding a way to accomplish what we need.

Before, when we used webforms, we were using our own custom DAL/ORM. But we would really like to switch to using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what I was trying to accomplish isn't supported. EF6 only supports create/update/delete stored procedures. Hopefully we can figure out a standard way of using MVC5 with the oracle DB we already have in place.

Thank you T McKeown for your efforts, your links helped lead me to my conclusion.

Comment: I am in the same situation, i want to use MVC 5 and have an existing huge oracle database, the insert,update,delete mapping is useful, but i need to map query procedures to the entities, now i was able to reverse engineer the code first classes\mapping from the tables by using EF Power Tools, but since the query procedures return the data using ref cursors and out parameters i will have to map the result to the entity manually, did you face that issue? and which solution are you going with(NHibernate, dotConnect, Custom?)

Comment: Our current projects are small enough that we have decided not to use stored procedures at the moment. I suspect we will go back to using our custom DAL and mapping the objects manually if/when we go back to stored procedures.

If you figure out a better solution add an answer, please!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 fundamental choices here:

**Code First:**

Design your models, and "wire" them up to your procedures that you have defined manually.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert%2fUpdate%2fDelete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping

**Database First:**

Point the EF at your DB and models will be created for you using your schema.  You can always call your custom procedures using Helper classes etc..  You would pass in the EF model and extract the attributes needed.

Personally, I prefer to code first simple POCO objects and wire them up as I see fit.  This gives you the most flexibility however it can get out of hand if you don't lay down an architecture first and abide by some governing patterns.

As for performance for high volume systems, similar to Ruby-On-Rails boiler plate MVC approaches can get unwieldy as they grow.  Using efficient procedures for CRUD will always win out over dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was wondering if you could point me to a resource or elaborate a little bit on the "wiring up" of a model and a stored procedure?

Comment: inside VS in your EF model classes you can right click and specify a stored procedure.

Comment: This is what you want, hopefully you can use this version:  http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert%2fUpdate%2fDelete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

I don't think this is what I want. The MapToStoredProcedures method seems to create insert/update/delete. I want to use stored procedures for when I map my database to objects in memory(reading data). The queries executed by the stored procedures I want to use are complex and pull data from multiple tables. I've been reading and I'm starting to feel like Entity Frame Work 6 isn't going to be what I end up using with this oracle data base. I was hoping there was a "nice" way to load my objects from a cursor returned by an already existent stored procedure.

Comment: Another problem I have ran into is I don't get the reverse engineer model from database option because oracles free .net provider doesn't support the most current version of Entity Framework. Starting to consider devart's provider or rolling back to a previous version of EF.