# Calling an Oracle SP that returns a refcursor from EF6

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6

The DB admin created a stored proc that takes 2 input params and returns a refcursor.

From what I've searched I need to add the SP via model, then from the model browser "Add Function Import".

However when I go to "Add Function Import" I click the "Get Column Information" button and get the message

```
The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns
```

Upon further research I came across that I would need to add a config setting to get around this.

Sample:

```
    <oracle.dataaccess.client>
                    <settings>
                        <add name="&quot;HR&quot;.&quot;UPDATESALARY&quot;.RefCursor.NEW_SALARY" value="implicitRefCursor bindinfo='mode=Output'" />
                        <add name="&quot;HR&quot;.&quot;UPDATESALARY&quot;.RefCursorMetaData.NEW_SALARY.Column.0" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=FIRST_NAME;BaseColumnName=FIRST_NAME;BaseSchemaName=HR;BaseTableName=EMPLOYEES;NATIVE_DATA_TYPE=Varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2;PROVIDER_DB_TYPE=String;ColumnSize=20'" />
                        <add name="&quot;HR&quot;.&quot;UPDATESALARY&quot;.RefCursorMetaData.NEW_SALARY.Column.1" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=SALARY;BaseColumnName=SALARY;BaseSchemaName=HR;BaseTableName=EMPLOYEES;NATIVE_DATA_TYPE=Number;ProviderType=Int32;DataType=System.Int32;ColumnSize=8'" />
                    </settings>
   </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

Now am I missing the boat here?  Would I need to do this every time a SP is created?
Wouldn't it just be easier to wrap the stored proc into a package where I can write code similiar to this to get the data?

```
            var ATests = db.Database.SqlQuery<ATest>(
                         "BEGIN PKG_TRAINING_SP.GETPERSONNELTRAINIGLIST(:personnel_Id_in, :base_date_in, :is_current_in, :result); end;",
                         param1, param2, param3, param4).ToList();
```

EDIT:
It appears that I wouldn't even need a package.  I could just tailor my statement to:

```
var ATests = db.Database.SqlQuery<ATest>(
                             "BEGIN MY_SCHEMA.MY_STORED_PROC_NAME(:personnel_Id_in, :base_date_in, :is_current_in, :result); end;",
                             param1, param2, param3, param4).ToList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can EF6 generate my model objects from a ref cursor returned by an oracle stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636005/can-ef6-generate-my-model-objects-from-a-ref-cursor-returned-by-an-oracle-stored)